# LazyColumn contains 20 TextField components, UI experiences freezing and time taking and scrolling lagging

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-asynclayoutinflater

The LazyColumn contains 20 TextField components. Upon navigating to this screen, the UI experiences freezing and time taking, and when scrolling, it exhibits lagging behavior.
HOW TO FIX IT

```
@Composable
fun LazyColumnTest(){
    LazyColumn{
        items(5){
            CardView()
        }
    }
}
```

cardView funtion here

```
@Composable
fun CardView(){
    val primaryColor = 0xFF8C1517 // Hex color value for #8C1517

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight()
    )
    {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {

            Text(
                text = "text1 ",
                color = Color(primaryColor),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp)
            )

            Row(
            ) {
                //Field 1
                var firstID by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = firstID, onValueChange = { newText ->
                        if (newText.text.length <= 12) { // Limit to 12 characters
                            firstID = newText
                        }
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    label = { Text(text = "First UID*", color = Color(primaryColor)) },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        focusedBorderColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        cursorColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        placeholderColor = Color(primaryColor)
                    )
                )
                //Field 2
                var secondId by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = secondId, onValueChange = {
                        secondId = it
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    label = { Text(text = "second ID", color = Color(primaryColor)) },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        focusedBorderColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        cursorColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        placeholderColor = Color(primaryColor)
                    )
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = firstID, onValueChange = { newText ->
                        if (newText.text.length <= 12) { // Limit to 12 characters
                            firstID = newText
                        }
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    label = { Text(text = "First UID*", color = Color(primaryColor)) },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        focusedBorderColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        cursorColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        placeholderColor = Color(primaryColor)
                    )
                )
                //Field 2
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = secondId, onValueChange = {
                        secondId = it
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    label = { Text(text = "second ID", color = Color(primaryColor)) },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        focusedBorderColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        cursorColor = Color(primaryColor),
                        placeholderColor = Color(primaryColor)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun AsyncContent() {
    var loading by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(500)
            loading = false
        }
    }



    if (loading) {
        LoadingScreen()
    } else {
         LazyColumnTest()
    }
}
```

MainActivity calling Composable Function AsyncContent()

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 setContent {
            SHFLTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                   AsyncContent()
                   
                }
            }
}
}
```

i have tried **Column** also that have smooth scroll but when navigating to that screen it was consuming more time . now trying with **lazyColumn** to achieve that but still not nothing helpful.

i want to achieve the 30 or more then it OutlinedTextField and other fields to load in single screen form that load smoothly and without taking long time and facing any kind  lag

as it working with async layout inflater to load long screen ui for xml

if anything else can help to achieve that so please let me know.

Thank you